# C++ Matrix with Arrays and Pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, matrix

I have a function for loading a matrix from a file. Now I am having problems with storing the elements on the right place.

Here is the important code which I have for storing the matrix. This code can´t be changed so I have to use this part as it is:

```
int **matrix
*matrix = new int[*rows * *columns];
```

Now I have a while-loop which is reading a textfile with the elements of the matrix.

But how can I store the value on the right place of the array?

Normally I would do something like this in the while-loop.

```
matrix[currentRow][currentColumn] = value;
```

But this would not work here as this isn´t a 2-dimension array.

Comment: Immediately dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is never a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the 2d indices into a 1d index.

```
int currentIndex = (currentRow * nColumns) + currentColumn;
matrix[currentIndex] = X; //actually (*matrix)[currentIndex] given your definition of matrix
```